# convert NSAffineTransform to CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, iphone

Here is my code from Mac OS X. I want to convert them to IOS.

```
NSAffineTransform *trans = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[trans translateXBy:(width - self.minWidth) yBy:0.0];
[trans concat];
```

I have no success to try CGAffineTransform. I even failed in the first step to declare CGAffineTransform.

```
CGFloat tx=width-self.minWidth;
CGFloat ty=0.0;
CGAffineTransform * trans=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tx, ty);
```

Error is aka struct CGAffineTransform
The purpose is to align everything to the right.

Thanks for you advices

Comment: How did you then use the CGAffineTransform to replace the concat method call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `*` from your variable because `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` returns a `CGAffineTransform` type, and not an `CGAffineTransform *`.

Replace

```
CGAffineTransform * trans=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tx, ty);
```

By

```
CGAffineTransform trans=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tx, ty);
```

Comment: I am so stupid.thank you so much. One more question. How should I convert [trans concat] to ios? I found CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransform t1, <#CGAffineTransform t2#>), but it has two inputs. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to check on stackoverflow, or the documentation. You will probably find an answer. Personnally, I don't have it, sorry